# File path in app.config file ? Window application?

Tags: winforms

In window application, I am accessing one file and the file path is declared in app.config file. After that I create exe for that application. Now the problem is when path is changed in app.config file when setup is created is this changes updated in setup or not?. If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: cant understand clearly. Are you using absolute paths or relative?

Comment: it is absolute path like C:/abc.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use relative paths, but As I understand, you cant use they.
So, only one possible solution in my opinion - define file path during instalation or add special dialog on programm first run to let user to define the path.